# i want to generate a loop that will "add" bonus points in each of the grade in the array, then compare the new marks with the criteria given

Tags: javascript

```js
var myMarks = [30, 45, 68, 32, 45];
var criteria = 30;
var bonusPoints = 5;
var total = [];
console.log(myMarks);
console.log(myMarks.length);
for (var i = 0; i < myMarks.length; i++) {
  total = myMarks[i] + bonusPoints;
  console.log(total);
  if (total < criteria) {
    console.log("failed");
  } else {
    console.log("passed");
  }
}
```

is the above code right in accordance with the question?

Comment: Please add the expected output

Comment: I want my code to output one time passed or failed after going through the whole array of marks, if any marks is less than criteria,the whole output should alert fail

Comment: expected output is :"Pass" or "Failed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `total` is an array, you should `push` values to it and get them by their indices:

```js
var myMarks = [30, 45, 68, 32, 45];
var criteria = 30;
var bonusPoints = 5;
var total = [];
console.log(myMarks);
console.log(myMarks.length);

for (var i = 0; i < myMarks.length; i++) {
  total.push(myMarks[i] + bonusPoints);
  console.log(total);
  
  if (total[i] < criteria) {
    console.log("failed");
  } else {
    console.log("passed");
  }
}
```

Here's the case when you want to output the result after the loop finishes:

```js
var myMarks = [30, 45, 68, 32, 45];
var criteria = 30;
var bonusPoints = 5;
var total = [];
var hasFailed = false;
 
for (var i = 0; i < myMarks.length; i++) {
  total.push(myMarks[i] + bonusPoints);
  
  if (total[i] < criteria) {
    hasFailed = true;
  }
}
 
console.log(hasFailed ? "Failed" : "Passed");
console.log(total);
```

Comment: I want my code to output one time passed or failed after going through the whole array of marks, if any marks is less than criteria,the whole output should alert fail

Comment: @SyedZeyadZeyad You can do that by introducing a new variable, let's say `var hasFailed = false`. Then in the loop you would check if any of the marks is less than the criteria, if it is, then set the `hasFailed` to true: `hasFailed = true`. And then after the for loop finishes, you can output "Failed" or "Passed", based on the `hasFailed` variable.

Comment: I have edited my answer and included that code as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` and `forEach()`.

```js
var myMarks = [30,45,68,32,45];
var criteria = 30; 
var bonusPoints = 5;
var flag = true;
myMarks.forEach(mark => {
  if (mark + bonusPoints < criteria) {
    flag = false;
  }
})
if (flag) 
   alert('passed');
else
   alert('failed');
```

Comment: Hmm, is there any reason to introduce two loops here where OP only had one?

Comment: He should need fixed mark array somewhere.

Comment: I want my code to output one time passed or failed after going through the whole array of marks, if any marks is less than criteria,the whole output should alert fail

Comment: @SyedZeyadZeyad, I updated the answer. Please check again.

Comment: @SyedZeyadZeyad, will you tick the answer if it is correct?

Comment: @Prime Sure thing

Answer (score 0):

You have set your variable total as an array so you can't just right total=myMarks[i]+bonusPoints. You should either have total[i] (so it adds relevant points to relevant indexes of the array or use array method push and write total.push(myMarks[i]+bonusPoints). And also in the if statement you should compare total [i] not total as you want to loop through each value of Array. That should do the trick

Comment: I want my code to output one time passed or failed after going through the whole array of marks, if any marks is less than criteria,the whole output should alert fail